# How to fix: Some, but not all, Windows 8.1 updates fail?

Tags: windows, windows-update, updates

Most Windows updates *are* working, but *some* updates are failing. On restart, i get "couldn't complete the updates. Undoing changes."

The failed updates seem to cause the *entire batch* to get rolled back. Thus, I'm forced to apply each update one-by-one.

With close to 200 updates, most requiring a full restart, this is taking days.

Previously, updates were not working at all, which i fixed by applying the following:

```
DISM /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
sfc /scannow
Update-agent-Windows8.1-KB3138615-x64.msu
WindowsUpdateDiagnostic.diagcab
```

and tweaking.com "windows_repair_aio" (which is just a wrapper around numerous Microsoft tools, including those listed above, and more).

Is my only option to continue applying the updates one at a time?

Here are the failed updates, so far:

- April, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB4015550)
- Security Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3155784)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3013538)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3013791)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3029432)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3029603)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3029606)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3033446)
- Update for Windows 8.1 for x64-based Systems (KB3034348)

Comment: So did you try the CHKDSK and DISM commands again this time? did they report problems?  Have you tried resetting Windows Update (stop update-related services, delete \windows\softwaredistribution folder, restart services), and then trying again?

Comment: i did not repeat the fixes i just performed. I did reset Windows update (which, as i understand, is used to fix the entire updater-- not individual updates).

Comment: If you performed a `Reset`, on Windows 8.1, that removes all personal files, application settings, and programs.  So I am guessing you don't actually mean you did that.  The failed updates are the quality rollup updates from 2015.  If you download each kb's installer by itself can you install them?  What is the last kb that was released in 2015 that was installed.  Without that information I can't tell you if the updates that won't installed have been superceeded by the updates you do have installed.  (Please do not comment you don't know how or can't do that)

Comment: share (Onedrive share link to a zip) the folder C:\Winodws\logs\CBS, so that I can analyze the log files.

Comment: @Ramhound and magicandre, thx 4 replies. i was worried there might be some fundamental flaw in my whole install, so i opted to just re-install Windows. Now, on this fresh install, i noticed the Updater just seems to spin forever (had same problem before). Yet, the OS seems stable and fast (except the clock keeps resetting itself to the wrong time). So, i turned off the Updater service and BITS (due to my limited 2GB ram, they slow down everything). I'm thinking of not bothering with any updates-- bad idea? To Ramhound's question, by "resetting updater", i meant re-registering the update dll's.

Comment: "I'm thinking of not bothering with any updates-- bad idea?"  --duh, of course that's a bad idea. Now i'm researching how to install just critical updates, using direct download instead of the updater service. https://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ Thx again for help!